# EasyAdminBundle many-to-many unidrectional entities relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine

After gone through many google links, I want to know what is the very common way to use "EasyAdminBundle" for doctrine entities mapping.

I am novice in symfony. I have already updated my doctrine schema as given below.

```
/* User Entity */
    class User{

    /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         *      )
         */
        protected $UserGroup;
    }

    /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function __toString(){

            return $this->getUserGroup();
        }

/* UserGroup Entity */
Class UserGroup{
//...

}
```

It has created a new table to refer two foreign keys User(id) UserGroup(id)

Now I try to open an user record in my EasyAdminBundle(BackOffice), It shoot an error when open a record.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup
>   could not be converted to string

As i have seen, EasyAdminBundle supports many-to-many entity relations. But I don't find any information about it.

Is there any way to do itself in config.yml?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a __toString() method in your UserGroup entity class which should return a string.